# How to use Excel formulas to Count?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

AIM:

Count:

- ID 1 or ID 2 is from rp
- Particular week (eg.week 80)
- Count only if the status is successful

**How the worksheet looks like:**
[image: 1]

**Sheet 2(details of the people and the division they are in):**

[image: 2]

**Sheet 3:**
[image: 3]

How my formula looks like:

> =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS('Sheet3'!$A$3:$A$4747,C1,'Sheet3'!$E$3:$E$4747,"1",'Sheet3'!$C$3:$C$4747,Sheet2!B2:B15))

The above formula does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: just clarifying, your question is ... on sheet1, you'd like there to be a formula in the matrix (e.g. highlighted in yellow), which provides a count (number) of the occurrences of "successful" from sheet3 while in the correct week no. (e.g. 80) and for the corresponding SP and RP references?

Comment: yes exactly! thank u:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your logic here:

> Count:
>
> ID 1 or ID 2 is from rp
>
> Particular week (eg.week 80)
>
> Count only if the status is successful

Referring to the print screen below for cell address (I simplified the IDs to 10s for easier read)

Formula in cell C3:

```
=COUNTIFS(I$3:I$10,$C$1,N$3:N$10,1,M$3:M$10,"Successful")
```

Add in a new column for Sheet3 called ID 1/2 from RP. Formula in cell N2:

```
=IF(OR(IFNA(INDEX($E$2:$E$7,MATCH(K2,$F$2:$F$7,0))="RP",FALSE),IFNA(INDEX($E$2:$E$7,MATCH(L2,$F$2:$F$7,0))="RP",FALSE)),1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have to modify your sheets a little bit. We are making your main formula a little simpler.

(1) On sheet2, on column D, set as Division Helper, starting from D2, use formula

```
=A2
```

(2) On sheet3, add one new columns after ID2, set as Division 1 and use formula

```
=vlookup(C1,Sheet2!B:D,3,false)
```

(3) On sheet3, add one new column after Division 1, set as Division 2 and use formula

```
=vlookup(D1,Sheet2!B:D,3,false)
```

(4) On sheet1, the yellow cell formula should be as follows (assumes 80 is at C1)

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet3!$A:$A,$C$1,Sheet3!$E:$E,$A2,Sheet3!$F:$F,B$2,Sheet3!$G:$G,1)"
```

You should be able to move this formula and it should still work since the references are fixed with $.